# Dreamweaver CS6 Default Colors.xml

Tags: dreamweaver

Could someone please provide me a link to the default Colors.xml file for Dreamweaver CS6? I've updated my preferences to a dark color scheme and would like to revert back to the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default color file for Dreamweaver CS6.
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19101303/Colors.xml

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring to the code color, you can change your color scheme back to "*Classic*" here:

> Preferences > Code Coloring > Theme (dropdown menu).

**Screenshot**: [Preferences panel screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ4nc.png)